# Apply smooth gradient color for list

Tags: html, css

I want to apply gradient color for item in the menu on hover and when link is active:

```
    <li class="nav-find-item active">
      <a class="nav-find-link " href="#!dashboard">
        <i class="fa fa-tachometer menu-icon"></i> 
        <span class="menu-title"> Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

here is my css style:

```
.sidebar-find .nav-find .nav-find-item.active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FFB88C, #191F28 10%);
}

.sidebar-find .nav-find .nav-find-item:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FFB88C, #191F28 10%);
}
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1ebs3g9/)

But it doesnt get me the desired result. What I want:
[image]

And what i get: [image]

I dont need the icon, just the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add a value to the first value, play around till you get the desired effect, something like this looks ok to me:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FFB88C -30%, #191F28 10%);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,184,140,0.38) 0%, rgba(25,31,40,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,184,140,0.38)), color-stop(100%, rgba(25,31,40,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,184,140,0.38) 0%, rgba(25,31,40,0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,184,140,0.38) 0%, rgba(25,31,40,0) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,184,140,0.38) 0%, rgba(25,31,40,0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,184,140,0.38) 0%, rgba(25,31,40,0) 100%);
```

Or play around with the settings [here](https://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'%5C-moz%5C-linear%5C-gradient%5C%28left%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28255%5C%2C184%5C%2C140%5C%2C0%5C.38%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%2825%5C%2C31%5C%2C40%5C%2C0%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B')